# Event is happening at Create time and not START time

Tags: mysql, events, insert, truncate

My Create EVENT headline is below. The creation executes properly, but the insert happens at the Create execution and not the STARTS time. Then, the TRUNCATEs happen at START time. I want the TRUNCATE to happen at START time first, and then the INSERT. I've done all the rearranging I can do, and it always happens in the wrong order. Note: the START time was after current_timestamp at time of execution.

```
 Create EVENT pkgtest
     ON SCHEDULE every 12 HOUR
     STARTS '2015-04-23 22:00:00'
     ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
     DO

     TRUNCATE TABLE
          workorders_pkgtest
     ;
     TRUNCATE TABLE
          tracking_buffer_pkgtest
     ;
     INSERT 
          INTO workorders_pkgtest
          (...
```

Comment: surround all of the sql statements with a `begin ... end` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `begin` and `end` around your series of statements. Also make sure you correctly set your delimiter

```
 delimiter //
 Create EVENT pkgtest
     ON SCHEDULE every 12 HOUR
     STARTS '2015-04-23 22:00:00'
     ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
     DO
       BEGIN
         TRUNCATE TABLE
           workorders_pkgtest
         ;
         TRUNCATE TABLE
           tracking_buffer_pkgtest
         ;
         INSERT 
           INTO workorders_pkgtest
           (... 
         ;
     END // 
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: That worked. Interesting. I have other compound-statement events that I didn't use the BEGIN/END in that worked fine. I guess I'll will be revisiting those. I wonder if it had anything to do with TRUNCATE, though my other events used DELETE. Thank you.